# mocha not return anything when using docker

Tags: docker, mocha.js, docker-compose, boot2docker

I have a nodejs app, which has some test return with mocha:

I have a docker-compose.yml with the following:

```
app:
  image: alvin/node
  working_dir: /app
  command: node app.js
  volumes:
    - .:/app
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  environment:
        - NODE_ENV=development
```

When I run `docker-compose up`, it works:

```
Recreating node_app_1
Attaching to node_app_1
[36mapp_1   |[0m Sever listen to port: 3000
```

But when I run `docker-compose run -d app mocha`, it does not return any result on the terminal. `alvin/node` docker image has mocha install globally.

Answer (score 0):

Passing the `-d` option specifically tells the containers to run in the background, so you naturally won't get the result on standard out. If you want to pick the result up, you can explicitly ask for the container's logs.

First find the container id via `docker ps`:

```
> docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
2a7901d40982        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon off"   7 seconds ago       Up 6 seconds        80/tcp, 443/tcp     loving_brattain
```

Then use `docker logs $CONTAINER_ID`.

```
> docker logs 2a7901d40982
```